# Apple indoor maps

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am following the tutorial from here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/241/

However, I can't move forward because I am getting

```
Use of undeclared type 'IMDFDecodableFeature'
```

and

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'IMDFError'
```

I was unsure if this is a part of MapKit or if the guy in the tutorial defined these in code he isn't showing, or if it is a compatibility issue as I am running swiftUI.

Also, if it is a compatibility issue can google maps or another vendor render user defined indoor maps?

Here is the snippet of code:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Feature<Properties: Decodable>: NSObject, IMDFDecodableFeature {
    let identifier: UUID
    let properties: Properties
    let geometry: [MKShape & MKGeoJSONObject]
    
    required init( feature: MKGeoJSONFeature) throws {
        guard let uuidString = feature.identifier else {
            throw IMDFError.invalidData
        }
        
        if let identifier = UUID( uuidString: uuidString) {
            self.identifier = identifier
        } else {
            throw IMDFError.invalidData
        }
        
        self.geometry = feature.geometry
        
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this class is part of *MapKit*. Instead, it seems to be part of the sample code [Displaying an Indoor Map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/displaying_an_indoor_map).

If you download it and have a look at the file `IMDFDecoder.swift`, you'll see `IMDFDecodableFeature` and `IMDFError` are declared there.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted but thank you! However would you mind linking the sample code, I can't find it anywhere?

Comment: There's a *Download* button on the linked page.

Comment: It was so obvious I couldn't see it. Thanks again!